# Android Studio and github, working with a team

Tags: git, android-studio, github

We are 6 developers and developing an android application in android studio. in VCS tab, I can upload my work to github in android studio but we could not figure how to connect all our computer and android studio to same github project. We have been searching for 3 days and couldn't find the solution.

Is there any way to connect all android studios to same github project with different github accounts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its been a while since I have used Android Studio and don't know all the functionality of its "VCS" tab. But for them to get all the changes you uploaded they need to pull the changes

```
git pull
```

This can be done from the terminal where they cloned the repository in the OS command prompt- you don't need to do anything in android studio since its easy enough to do from command line.

Alternatively you can also look into downloading a github client that has fancy buttons to do all of this for you.

Comment: in VCS tab I can control git options

Still, I did not get how to connect all android studios to same github project. I have github client but I don't know how it can be useful in my situation, also, how to use git pull command? Could you clarify your answer please

Comment: If you have git client you can click on repository tab and then click on pull to pull in changes. 

I'm not sure what you mean by connect android studios to the same github project. They have to run `git clone` with the url of the repository on github (if you go to your github project page the link is right there) and then they will be synced with the github project version. Then they can run commands like git pull. Pushing will be dependent on project settings, you might have to tweak them on github.com to allow them to push their changes to the main branch.